# How can I run pytesseract Python library in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, machine-learning, ubuntu-22.04

I'm detecting text from images in python. I'm using **pytesseract 0.3.10** . but it seems this library is just working on windows OS while I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. in all examples codes using cmd address like this.

```
pt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
```

how can I shange this to run on ubuntu. by the way I'm using jupyter-lab.

I changed this code to other fromats like this:

original example code:

```
pt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
```

I changed code to :

```
pt.pytesseract.tesseract_user_cmd = 'user/share/...'
```

or

```
pt.pytesseract.tesseract_user_terminal = 'user/share/...'
```

Comment: `which tesseract` in the terminal

Comment: Also start the path with a `/`

Comment: thank you, I changed it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to update and upgrade repos:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

To install pytesseract, run this command

```
pip install pytesseract
```

To support languages other than English, use this command along with upper one:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr-tam
```

Language examples:

- eng -> English
- guj -> Gujarati
- tam -> tamil

You can find more: just use

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

and press tab to get all possibilities

Answer (score 1):

Add Tesseract OCR 5 PPA to your system.
To add the Tesseract OCR 5 PPA to your system, run the command below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr-devel
```

Install Tesseract on Ubuntu
Run the command :

```
sudo apt install -y tesseract-ocr
```

Once installation is complete update your system

```
sudo apt update
```